# A good programming language for programming code challenges

Tags: scripting, programming-languages

From time to time you come across some interesting code or programming challenges, 
such as the ones in [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), some job interview challenges like [greplin](http://challenge.greplin.com/), or any of the other script challenges that are [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692/where-can-you-find-fun-educational-programming-challenges).

All these require some fast, agile programming language with some kind of quick way to see the results, preferably command line. There's no need to worry about readability of the code or such. 
 You just need an answer, and fast.

What is a good language to solve these challenges? What is the best hands-on method for solving, if you have to choose a language and learn it from the start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project Euler tells you that lots of languages are suitable.  Those problems are solved in every language from Perl to C#.

The language you should use for challenges is either the one you know best or the one you're trying to learn right now.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean fast coding, rather than fast execution, I suggest looking at Python. It's very high level (thus, you can code powerful things quickly) and has an interactive mode that lets you see results immediately, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 - I think Python's combination of functional and object-oriented programming, plus an interactive environment, make it my choice as well.  I'll bet every Project Euler question has several Python implementations.  Do they keep statistics on most popular language there?  It would be telling.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your description:

> You just need an answer, and fast.

I assume you are talking about runtime. If this is the case, C++ is the way to go.

However if you just started programming and you need to learn the basics, I would suggest Python.

Comment: Because C++ is totally the fastest language in the whole world, no exceptions.

Comment: Well, ofcourse I could suggest Assembly and even Machine Code, but would that be helpful?

Comment: Since when is runtime the biggest impediment for succeeding at challenges?  For sites like Top Coder, the winner is usually the one that completes an implementation first.  That combines development and run times.  Which one would you bet is greater?

Answer (score 1):

You need an answer and fast

Only if that is the way you find programming acceptable.

Or if you intend to not gain experience in teamplay programming.

You can't fool yourself :/

I just gave this advice to a similar question for a game development language choice:

```
1) What is my goal?

2) What engine is going to help me , or framework, platform, what are you depending on?

3) What languages can I use to accomadate step one and respect step 2
```

Basically what you can do is skip step 2 really.

And it's really about what YOU want. If you REALLY want to spend a lot of time working to quick results ( Which I can respect, I'm not trying to sound all-in attack mode here), you should consider C++. It allows you to dig deep, but it can be quick , even sloppy, if need be. But you do need a little XP in it.